# How to implement file picker inside a bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement a camera UI that has option to choose multiple images from the user's gallery by dragging up a bottom sheet. I am using the `file_picker` plugin to access my gallery. Is there any way to have it open in my bottom sheet rather than occupying the entire screen? The `getMultiFilePath()` makes a method channel call to access the platform file picker which opens up in full screen. UI is similar to WhatsApp status camera UI.

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to Stackoverflow!**

The `file_picker` plugin provides you the picking functionality but it has it's own UI, as it calls the Native File Picker functions, so you can't override that.

What you can do is to check out the plugins below which I *think* will give you the path to all the gallery images. Then you can use `GridView` to show them in a bottom sheet. Once you show them in the bottom sheet, you can wrap the Image widgets in an InkWell to handle `onTap` and `onLongPress` to select and unselect images.

[image_gallery 1.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery)
[storage_path 0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/storage_path)

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: Thanks. I realised that and have started with implementation using photo_manager library. Would you recommend using image_gallery 1.2.0 or storage_path 0.2.0 over photo_manager 0.4.8?

Comment: I think `photo_manager` is the best, I saw it sometime ago, just couldn't find it when answering so the above two were also the 2nd best options.